# is aes_decrypt function available for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

2 days ago at the Google Next conference there was a nice session over BigQuery where a pattern to handle PII data and Right To Be Forgotten (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gYUGv_omJA at 22:30).

The implementation uses a aes_decrypt() function, which I cannot find on the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators ) or anywhere.

Does somebody know if Google has fully released it? If no, any target date to make it GA?

Comment: good catch - https://youtu.be/1gYUGv_omJA?t=1386 - i was not able to find it anywhere nor it worked for me. I feel like it was prematurely revealed :o) would be interesting to know. at the same time SO is not place for this type of question (just as FYI) - [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100182) is better place for this

Comment: I created [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111927939) on the issue tracker, which has a link to the enrollment form.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Do you also know if Google also has some public documentation about the whole workflow regarding this PII encrypted data? Video was great but lot of questions remain open (ex: how to protect the key table, how data is encrypted by service application that publish to BigQuery etc)

Comment: The documentation goes into some of these details (shared after being whitelisted).

Comment: The link @ElliottBrossard is referring to is here. [Click this link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcxK1_C_wxBvdJUC0KPIiKM_kkTlaIHIhlRccd0TwJ6AfL_w/viewform) to enroll and get whitelisted to use these functions.